# Any Hosted CI service that natively support JUnit XML reports?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, junit, continuous-integration

Does anyobdy know a good solid CI service that provides the common features of build parallelization BUT also support for Junit reports?

The current ones that we have looked at (semaphoreapp, circleCI, travisCI,...) are good but relatively useless as we have to manually investigate what tests failed, since when, and how often, thus negating a lot of the benefits of a hosted service.

Things that we're looking to know (and are all provided by JUnit / Jenkins):

- If the build failed, because of what test cases?
- Total Number of Failures / Total Number of Tests (trends to better analyze things)
- Individual Track record of any test (so we know exactly when it was broken, whether it's intermittent,...)

Comment: I would recommend [Teamcity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/)

- It has all features you requested
- It's free up to maximum of 20 build configurations

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned the most famous CI services but there are alternatives where you can get a higher customization level, like installing plugins, fine configuration, etc.

[CloudBees](http://www.cloudbees.com/) and [ClinkerHQ](http://clinkerhq.com) are both based on Jenkins offered as a service. You can also get very useful metrics (coverage, failures, graphs, execution times, etc.) thanks to Jenkins Plugins and SonarQube. I think Jenkins and SonarQube are a perfect couple for you.

Notifications are very important too. You want to be notified when something is wrong. This feature is available on both.

Regards,
Antonio.

DISCLAIMER: I'm deeply involved in ClinkerHQ